# `GLIBC_2.34' not found

Tags: glibc

I am trying to run an up in my raspberry pi (4b with latest bullsey) which I have cross-compiled.
The error am encountering is: “/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found”

When I installed the toolchain I simply did:
sudo apt install libssl-dev lib6-dev libncurses5-dev
Is there anyway to install the toolchain and cherry pick the compatible version?
Or alternatively to link to earlier versions?

Comment: What does `strings /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC` return? On my Debian 11 VM, the highest version was 2.30.

Comment: @ajgringo619 the version is 2.31 on the rbpi.

Comment: Unless you want to change to **Debian Sid** (easy, but risky), you could follow the advice given here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272606/locally-installing-glibc-2-23-causes-all-programs-to-segfault?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up doing static linking (-static) for that one.